# Is that possible to track Intercom event inside nodeJS function?

Tags: intercom

What I have is some backend function (Cloud function) that runs whenever an user cancelled subscription. Is there a way to run something like:

```
Intercom("track", "sub_cancel", { ...userMeta })
```

on the backend side, inside that function?

I took a look at https://github.com/intercom/intercom-node but it seems it only allows to create events, there's nothing about tracking them.

Answer (score 0):

For now it looks like creating an event is the same as submitting/tracking them.

The API doesn't seem to have any way to create events without submitting them at the moment https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference#submitting-events

Using the example code in the repo https://github.com/intercom/intercom-node#events I managed to track 2 instances of the same event at different times

```
// Create a event
client.events.create({
  event_name: 'Foo',
  created_at: 1439826340,
  user_id: 'bar',
  metadata: { type: 'baz' }
}, function (d) {
  console.log(d);
});
```

[image: screenshot of code producing multiple events]